# Netplan did not automatically connect to network

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, netplan, cloud-init

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 for Raspberry Pi 4 with a `network-config` file that describes my Wi-Fi networks. This file was automatically copied to `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`.

However, the RPi did not connect to the network automatically.

When I ran `sudo netplan --debug apply` it did connect (log below).

But I'd like to understand why it didn't work automatically in the first place, so I don't need console access to kick off the network connection for each device.

```
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.874: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.875: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.875: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'AccessPointA'
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.875: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'AccessPointB'
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.875: wlan0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.875: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.875: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.875: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.876: Generating output files..
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.877: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.877: wlan0: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlan0.conf
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.877: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.wants/netplan-wpa@wlan0.service
** (generate:1719): DEBUG: 18:47:11.878: NetworkManager: definition wlan0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:eth0 not found in {}
DEBUG:wlan0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  vlans: {}
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      access-points:
        AccessPointA:
          password: asdf
        AccessPointB:
          password: asdf
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eth0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for wlan0
```

I do see this in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`:

```
network_state.py[WARNING]: Wifi configuration is only available to distros withnetplan rendering support.
```

This message seems to come from [this part of cloud-init](https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-init/tree/cloudinit/net/network_state.py?h=ubuntu/bionic#n699).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you are affected by https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1892851.  We anticipate this bug being fixed for Ubuntu 20.10 shortly, and for the fix to be backported to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS soon.  We have not committed at this time to backporting this fix to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; the quickest way for you to get the fix will be to use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS intead of 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I tried this today on 20.04.2 LTS, which came with netplan 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2. It seems to have had the same behavior though. Was the fix backported to Focal?

Comment: yes, this was fixed in netplan 0.100 and focal has netplan 0.101.